# java and xml, use of Element

Tags: java, xml, recursion, tree-traversal

i'm a beginner in java and XML , but I have a task to perform and I don't know how to use a recursive function which uses Element.
I made this program.

public class JDOM2
{
    private static final String xmlroutes = "C://Users//Thomas//Desktop//routes.xml";

```
static Element root;

public static void main(String[] args) throws JDOMException, IOException
{
    // the SAXBuilder is the easiest way to create the JDOM2 objects.
    SAXBuilder jdomBuilder = new SAXBuilder();

    // jdomDocument is the JDOM2 Object
    Document jdomDocument = jdomBuilder.build(xmlroutes);                                                                    
    root = jdomDocument.getRootElement();

    List <Element> location_properties = root.getChildren("LOCATION_PROPERTIES");
    Iterator<Element> it = location_properties.iterator();
    Element loc = it.next();

    rootiteration();
}  


public static void rootiteration()
{
    int time;
    List <Element> location_properties = root.getChildren("LOCATION_PROPERTIES");
    Iterator<Element> it = location_properties.iterator();
    Element loc = it.next();
        if(loc.getAttributeValue("NAME").startsWith("STN")== true)
        {    
            List <Element> segment_properties = loc.getChildren("SEGMENT_PROPERTIES");
            Iterator<Element> it2 = segment_properties.iterator();
            Element seg = it2.next();
            List <Element> next_location = seg.getChildren("NEXT_LOCATION");
            for (Element next: next_location)
            {
                if(next.getAttributeValue("NAME").startsWith("STN")== true)
                {
                    System.out.print("Arrival : " +next.getAttributeValue("NAME"));
                    int L = Integer.parseInt(next.getAttributeValue("LENGTH"));
                    int S = Integer.parseInt(next.getAttributeValue("SPEED"));
                    time = L/S;
                    System.out.println("  ---  Time to go : "+time+" seconds");
                }
                if(next.getAttributeValue("NAME").startsWith("STN")== false)
                {
                    recursive();  // I think the problem is here but I may have done some other mistakes.
                }
            }
        }

}

public static int recursive(Element parent, int t0, Element child) throws IOException 
{
    List <Element> location_properties = root.getChildren("LOCATION_PROPERTIES");
    Iterator <Element> i = location_properties.iterator();     
    int t1 = 0;
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        child = (Element) i.next();
        int L = Integer.parseInt(child.getChild("SEGMENT_PROPERTIES").getChild("NEXT_LOCATION").getAttributeValue("LENGTH"));
        int S = Integer.parseInt(child.getChild("SEGMENT_PROPERTIES").getChild("NEXT_LOCATION").getAttributeValue("SPEED"));
        t1 = L/S;
        //t1 = time_between();
        if (child.getAttributeValue("NAME").startsWith("STN")== true)
        {
            System.out.println("From : "+parent+" to "+child+"  ---  Time to go : "+t1+" seconds");
            System.out.println(child.getAttributeValue("NAME")); 
            System.out.println(parent);
        }
        if (child.getAttributeValue("NAME").startsWith("X")== true) // child is not STN, recurse
        {
            recursive(parent, t0 + t1,child);
            System.out.println("From : "+parent+" to "+child+"  ---  Time to go : "+t1+" seconds");
            //    t0 = t0 + t1;
        }
    }
    return t0;
}
```

This is supposed to calculate the time between 2 Elements. King of this way :

I need two functions, one which iterates over all root elements, and starts the tree traversal at a starting STN, and a recursive function that traverse the tree until it finds an ending STN.

To have something like that :

```
Departure Station : STN10
Arrival : X535  ---  Time to go : 16 seconds
Arrival : X536  ---  Time to go : 2 seconds
Arrival : X537  --- ...
Arrival : STN26 ---  Total time to Station : ...

Departure Station : STN11
Arrival : X535 --- 
...And so on.
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I make my program work? When I call the function recursive in "rootIteration", I need parameters in the call of the function recursive but I don't know how Element works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the second method as follows and it would work:

```
public static int recursive(Element root, int t0, Element current) throws IOException 
{
    List <Element> location_properties = current.getChildren("LOCATION_PROPERTIES");
    Iterator <Element> i = location_properties.iterator();     
    int t1 = 0;
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        child = (Element) i.next();
        int L = Integer.parseInt(child.getChild("SEGMENT_PROPERTIES").getChild("NEXT_LOCATION").getAttributeValue("LENGTH"));
        int S = Integer.parseInt(child.getChild("SEGMENT_PROPERTIES").getChild("NEXT_LOCATION").getAttributeValue("SPEED"));
        t1 = L/S;
        //t1 = time_between();
        if (child.getAttributeValue("NAME").startsWith("STN")== true)
        {
            System.out.println("From : "+root+" to "+child+"  ---  Time to go : "+t1+" seconds");
            System.out.println(child.getAttributeValue("NAME")); 
        }
        if (child.getAttributeValue("NAME").startsWith("X")== true) // child is not STN, recurse
        {
            recursive(root, t0 + t1, child);
        }
    }
    return t0;
}
```

Everytime a non-STN element is encountered the `child` element will be passed to the `recursive` method as the `current` element.
You will have to call this method using the `root` element as the `root` parameter and the same element as the `current` parameter. i.e., `recursive(root, 0, root)`.

Please note that I could not test this as the xml file is not accessible to me. Hope this helps.

Comment: I can send you an email with the file if you want, or try this link : 
http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/532301/routes-xml.html

Comment: It isn't really working.. because if you look at the main, the element root is already used

Comment: The way that you did it wasn't working very well. Plus I mustn't put a number in the call of the function, it's a variable which have to be in .

Answer (score 0):

For those who can be interested, I used this function to re-use the string "next.getAttributeValue("NAME")" as an element.

```
 public static Element getElembyName(final String name){
    List <Element> location_properties = root.getChildren("LOCATION_PROPERTIES");
    for (Element loc : location_properties)
    {
        if(loc.getAttributeValue("NAME").equals(name))
            return loc;
    }
    return null;
}
```